# SpeechRecognition network error (electronjs)

Tags: reactjs, electron

Electron: v4.0.8
React: v16.8.4
I build an app using electron, after implementing SpeechRecognition i get a Network error after every recognition start. However it's working fine on chrome. 
Does anyone have a solution or an alternative to make that work on electron ?

Comment: I think you'll have to give a lot more detail for somebody to help you. Can you share your code? What does the error message say?

Comment: Okay ! so the main idea is : Converting speech to text, i used the Web Speech API (recognition service) to do that.
I run my app on Chrome browser without any issues.
However when i run it using electron, the WebkitSpeechRecognition throws an error : Network.
I've found somewhere that it's related to the google_api_key. but i couldn't solve that
thanks